# Using GROUP BY and conditional ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm having a problem with a query to get the right data using **"group by"** and an conditional **"order by"**.
Here is the query without **"group by"**:

```
SELECT gc.GES_PERSONAL_ID AS pid, gc.FPVAL AS fpval, gc.FECHA_HORA AS fh, gc.ENTRADA_SALIDA AS es
FROM ges_capturador AS gc
WHERE (gc.FPVAL >= '2013-12-25' AND gc.FPVAL <= '2013-12-26')
AND gc.GES_PERSONAL_ID=138
AND gc.GES_BANDERA_ID=1
AND gc.ESTADO=true
AND (gc.ENTRADA_SALIDA=1 OR gc.ENTRADA_SALIDA=0)
ORDER BY gc.FPVAL, CASE gc.ENTRADA_SALIDA WHEN 1 THEN gc.FH END ASC, CASE WHEN gc.ENTRADA_SALIDA = 0 THEN gc.FH END DESC
```

With that query I get all data of these days and ordered as I want. If ENTRADA_SALIDA = 1 then sort of fh field is ASC and when is 0, sort is DESC.

```
+------+------------+---------------------+------+
| pid  | fpval      | fh                  | es   |
+------+------------+---------------------+------+
|  138 | 2013-12-25 | 2013-12-26 01:06:16 |    0 |
|  138 | 2013-12-25 | 2013-12-26 01:05:40 |    0 |
|  138 | 2013-12-25 | 2013-12-25 14:29:00 |    0 |
|  138 | 2013-12-25 | 2013-12-25 14:28:20 |    1 |
|  138 | 2013-12-25 | 2013-12-25 14:29:11 |    1 |
+------+------------+---------------------+------+
```

Well, the problem is that I want the first register of each case (ENTRADA_SALIDA => 0 and 1). But, this is the query adding **"group by"** to remove those registers that I don't want in my result:

```
SELECT gc.GES_PERSONAL_ID AS pid, gc.FPVAL AS fpval, gc.FECHA_HORA AS fh, gc.ENTRADA_SALIDA AS es
FROM ges_capturador AS gc
WHERE (gc.FPVAL>='2013-12-25' AND gc.FPVAL<='2013-12-26')
AND gc.GES_PERSONAL_ID=138
AND gc.GES_BANDERA_ID=1
AND gc.ESTADO=true
AND (gc.ENTRADA_SALIDA=1 OR gc.ENTRADA_SALIDA=0)
GROUP BY gc.GES_PERSONAL_ID,gc.FPVAL,gc.ENTRADA_SALIDA
ORDER BY gc.FPVAL, CASE gc.ENTRADA_SALIDA WHEN 1 THEN gc.FH END ASC, CASE WHEN gc.ENTRADA_SALIDA = 0 THEN gc.FH END DESC
```

And the result of this query is:

```
+------+------------+---------------------+------+
| pid  | fpval      | fh                  | es   |
+------+------------+---------------------+------+
|  138 | 2013-12-25 | 2013-12-25 14:29:00 |    0 |
|  138 | 2013-12-25 | 2013-12-25 14:29:11 |    1 |
+------+------------+---------------------+------+
```

As you can see, I don't get the first result of each case in the **"es"** field.

The result that I need is:

```
+------+------------+---------------------+------+
| pid  | fpval      | fh                  | es   |
+------+------------+---------------------+------+
|  138 | 2013-12-25 | 2013-12-26 01:06:16 |    0 |
|  138 | 2013-12-25 | 2013-12-25 14:28:20 |    1 |
+------+------------+---------------------+------+
```

Comment: why aren't you adding an ELSE/DEFAULT to your CASE?

Comment: You could try using a where clause instead of order by. Something like `where FPVAL = (select min(FPVAL) from ges_capturator)...`

Comment: Showing us output without showing input is perverse. Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Don't misuse `GROUP BY`. It has but one purpose: to control how aggregation is grouped. It is entirely meaningless unless your query also contains aggregate functions like SUM() or GROUP_CONCAT(). There's an oddball extension to it in MySQL which causes it to return unpredictable results in these cases.

Comment: OK, thanks for your replies. I removed the condition in order by and change the the select part `gc.FECHA_HORA AS fh` by `CASE gc.ENTRADA_SALIDA WHEN 1 THEN MIN(gc.FECHA_HORA) ELSE MAX(gc.FECHA_HORA) END AS fh` and now is working fine. Thanks all again.